# Calculating the the exact width of the text and a lettrine

Tags: indentation, calculations, lettrine

This is one question which technically could be broken into two minor questions.

I am using a `lettrine` and some verse text, but the calculation to determine how much to indent the text does not always work properly.

I have tried to set the `\titlespacing` of the `\section` to `runin`, but it did not come out as expected.

Here is an example of the code, reduced as much as I could to show the failure and a working example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\setmainfont{Cardo}

\newcounter{bingo}
\newlength\howwide

\newcommand\defhowwide{
    \setcounter{bingo}{\value{section}}
    %To sync the width with the next section to display
    \addtocounter{bingo}{1}
    \settowidth{\howwide}{\Huge{\thebingo}}
    }

% sections and subsections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{}{\lettrine{\thesection}}{0pt}{}[\vskip-1\baselineskip]
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\small\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\howwide}{-1pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength\NumLen
\newlength\LinLen
% indents one line of text. Indentation= width of section number + 1em
\newcommand\IndOne{%
  \setlength\NumLen{\howwide}
  \addtolength\NumLen{0.5em}
  \setlength\LinLen{\dimexpr\textwidth-\NumLen}%\the\NumLen\the\LinLen
  \parshape 2 \NumLen \LinLen 0pt \textwidth}
% indents two lines of text. Indentation= width of section number + 1em
\newcommand\IndTwo{%
  \setlength\NumLen{\howwide}
  \addtolength\NumLen{0.5em}
  \setlength\LinLen{\dimexpr\textwidth-\NumLen}%\the\NumLen\the\LinLen
  \parshape 3 \NumLen \LinLen \NumLen \LinLen 0pt \textwidth}

\usepackage{layouts}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy

\begin{document}
\newlength{\myIndent}

\setcounter{section}{4}
\defhowwide
\section{}
\settowidth{\myIndent}
{\IndOne Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom.}
\ifdimless{\myIndent}
{\textwidth-\howwide}
{\IndOne Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom. \stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection{} \IndOne Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel.}
{\IndTwo Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom. \stepcounter{subsection} \subsection{} Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel.}
\printinunitsof{pt}
\prntlen{\myIndent} myIndent\\
\prntlen{\textwidth} textwidth\\
\prntlen{\linewidth} linewidth\\
\prntlen{\howwide} howwide\\
\prntlen{\LinLen} LinLen\\
\prntlen{\NumLen} NumLen
\subsection{} Julle goud en silwer is verroes, en hulle roes sal tot 'n getuienis teen julle wees en sal soos 'n vuur julle vlees verteer. Julle het skatte vergader in die laaste dae.

\setcounter{section}{9}
\defhowwide
\section{}
\settowidth{\myIndent}
{\IndOne Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom.}
\ifdimless{\myIndent}
{\textwidth-\howwide}
{\IndOne Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom. \stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection{} \IndOne Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel.}
{\IndTwo Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom. \stepcounter{subsection} \subsection{} Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel.}
\printinunitsof{pt}
\prntlen{\myIndent} myIndent\\
\prntlen{\textwidth} textwidth\\
\prntlen{\linewidth} linewidth\\
\prntlen{\howwide} howwide\\
\prntlen{\LinLen} LinLen\\
\prntlen{\NumLen} NumLen
\subsection{} Julle goud en silwer is verroes, en hulle roes sal tot 'n getuienis teen julle wees en sal soos 'n vuur julle vlees verteer. Julle het skatte vergader in die laaste dae.
\end{document}
```

In general the code works well but in some instances still ends up overlapping the text as in this screenshot.

[image: Problem displayed]

I guess if I can find the exact width of the `lettrine` I would be able to do the `\ifdimless{\myIndent}{\textwidth-\howwide}...` calculation more accurately.

---

As mentioned below in the comments. Compile using XeLaTeX and Cardo font to get the same results.

Comment: In case anybody wants to compile this, I'm assuming you need to use XeLaTeX and the [Cardo](http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html) font‽

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's quite late, but I saw this question linked to another one of yours.

I think that `lettrine` is not the correct way to solve your problem. Here's a different way to cope with it.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{Cardo}

\newcommand{\Sectionnumber}{%
  \sbox\Sectionbox{\smash{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
    \fontsize{2.2\baselineskip}{0}\selectfont\theSection}}\enspace}}

\newcounter{Section}
\newcounter{Subsection}[Section]
\newlength{\Sectionwidth}
\newif\ifFirstSubsection
\newsavebox{\Sectionbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Section}{\par\vskip\z@ \@plus 2\p@
  \FirstSubsectiontrue\clubpenalty\@M
  \refstepcounter{Section}\stepcounter{Subsection}%
  \Sectionnumber\setlength{\Sectionwidth}{\wd\Sectionbox}%
  \hangindent\Sectionwidth\hangafter-2
  \leavevmode\llap{\box\Sectionbox}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\Subsection}{%
  \par\clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
  \ifFirstSubsection
    \ifnum\prevgraf=\@ne\nobreak\hspace*{\Sectionwidth}\fi
    \FirstSubsectionfalse
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{Subsection}\textbf{\theSubsection}\enspace\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0pt


\begin{document}

\setcounter{Section}{8}

\Section Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom.

\Subsection Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel.

\Subsection Julle goud en silwer is verroes, en hulle roes sal tot 'n getuienis 
teen julle wees en sal soos 'n vuur julle vlees verteer. Julle het skatte vergader
in die laaste dae.

\Section Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom.

\Subsection Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel.

\Subsection Julle goud en silwer is verroes, en hulle roes sal tot 'n getuienis 
teen julle wees en sal soos 'n vuur julle vlees verteer. Julle het skatte vergader
in die laaste dae.

\end{document}
```

The trick is counting the line of the `\Section` paragraph with the internal counter `\prevgraf`. If we are in the first subsection after a section *and* the section paragraph is only one line long, then an indent is inserted to get the correct spacing.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Thanks. Might be what I've been looking for in the first place.

Comment: The only problem with this solution seems to be that it interferes with my `section` and `subsection` counters which I use to set the `titlemarks`. This is not present in the MWE above though. Where do I need to insert the `\stepcounter{subsection}` code to let the `subsection` sync up with the `Subsection`? I've found a spot for the `\stepcounter{section}` just inside `\newcommand{\Section}` but  inside `\newcommand{\Subsection}`, `\stepcounter{subsection}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @McGafter It's difficult to say, without seeing the code. But I guess you can use the `Section` and `Subsection` counters; why not?

Comment: I'm not sure how. I'll post my edit of your solution as an answer to this question reduced as much as I can to an MWE.

Comment: Maybe it is worth that the problem is not generated by any package at all. It is just `\parshape` that is cancelled after each pargraph. A more general solution would be to save the indentation before `\par` in `\subsection`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple macro similar to what `lettrine` package does. The [LaTeX source](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/attachments/article/106/HarfeAval-example.tex) and [its PDF output](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/attachments/article/106/HarfeAval-example.pdf). This is done mainly for RTL (in this case Persian). Note that the macro programming is done in Persian as xepersian provides the tools for Persian macro programming so if you need equivalent English commands, then have a look at `xepersian` documentation.

Also note that `lettrine` package is fully supported by `bidi` package but `picins` is not supported by `bidi` package and you may get some problems with it for typesetting RTL text (Why is not it supported? Well, because picins is written in LaTeX2.09, not a free package and more importantly not included in TeXLive).

Answer (score 4):

Consider this not so much an answer to your question, but rather a suggestion. Some reference to the problems you are experiencing are added at the end of the post. It seems like you're trying to typeset some chapters and verses from the book of James - [Afrikaanse Bybel: Jakobus](http://www.wordplanet.org/af/59/5.htm). Understandably [`lettrine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) seems like a good option here. However, as you have already noted, it doesn't enjoy short paragraphs (typical in your case if you're typesetting verses as a sectional item or a paragraph). Here is a rather simple alternative using the [`picins` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/picins).

`picins` provides

```
\parpic(<width>,<height>)(<x-offset>,<y-offset>)[<options>][<position>]{<stuff>}
```

that typesets `<stuff>` in a similar manner that [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) does. I just sometimes find it easier to work with. `<option>` allows some elementary border/shadow commands, and `<position>` specifies the location (left `l` or right `r`) where `picins` will put the paragraph picture. Additional movement is provided by the offset parameters. So, instead of fiddling with `lettrine` and [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) definitions, the above provides a clean interface and very readable code. Well, that is mainly due to some macro writing...

Since I do not have the Cardo font and have stripped your MWE down, the following does not require `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a5paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{picins}% http://ctan.org/pkg/picins
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace

\newcounter{bchapter} \renewcommand{\thebchapter}{\Huge\arabic{bchapter}}% Chapter
\newcounter{bverse}[bchapter] \renewcommand{\thebverse}{\textbf{\arabic{bverse}}}% Verse
\newcommand{\bchapter}{%
  \refstepcounter{bchapter}% Increment counter and allow referencing (\stepcounter would also work)
  \setcounter{bverse}{1}% First verse doesn't need to typeset '1'
  \setbox0=\hbox{\Huge\thebchapter}% Store \Huge chapter number in box0
  \needspace{\ht0}% Need at least the height of box0
  \pichskip{5pt}\noindent\parpic(\wd0,\ht0)(0pt,20pt)[][r]{\usebox0}% Insert \Huge chapter number
}%
\newcommand{\bverse}{%
  \par\refstepcounter{bverse}% Increment counter and allow referencing (\stepcounter would also work)
  \thebverse~\ignorespaces%
}

% Remove paragraph indentation & skip
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\bchapter Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom. 
\bverse Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel. 
\bverse Julle goud en silwer is verroes, en hulle roes sal tot 'n getuienis teen julle wees en sal soos ‘n vuur julle vlees verteer. Julle het skatte vergader in die laaste dae. 
\bverse Kyk, die loon van die arbeiders wat julle lande afgeoes het, wat deur julle agtergehou is, roep uit; en die geroep van die maaiers het gekom tot in die ore van die Here van die leërskare. 
\bverse Julle het op die aarde 'n weelderige en losbandige lewe gelei; julle het jul harte vet gevoer soos op ‘n slagdag. 
\bverse Veroordeel, vermoor het julle die regverdige; hy versit hom nie teen julle nie. 
\bverse Wees dan geduldig, broeders, tot op die wederkoms van die Here. Kyk, die landbouer wag op die kostelike vrug van die aarde en het geduld daarmee totdat dit die vroe\"e en die laat re\"en ontvang het. 
\bverse Julle moet ook geduldig wees; versterk julle harte, want die wederkoms van die Here is naby. 
\bverse Moenie teen mekaar sug nie, broeders, sodat julle nie veroordeel word nie. Kyk, die Regter staan voor die deur. 
\bverse Neem as voorbeeld van lyding, my broeders, en van geduld die profete wat in die Naam van die Here gespreek het. 
\bverse Kyk, ons reken hulle geluksalig wat verdra. Julle het gehoor van die lydsaamheid van Job, en julle het die einddoel van die Here met hom gesien, dat die Here vol medelye en ontferming is. 
\bverse Maar bo alles, my broeders, moenie sweer nie: nie by die hemel nie, ook nie by die aarde nie en ook geen ander eed nie; maar laat julle ja ja wees en julle nee nee, sodat julle nie onder ‘n oordeel val nie. 
\bverse Is daar iemand onder julle wat ly? Laat hom bid. Is iemand opgeruimd? Laat hom psalmsing. 
\bverse Is daar iemand siek onder julle? Laat hom die ouderlinge van die gemeente inroep, en laat hulle oor hom bid nadat hulle hom in die Naam van die Here met olie gesalf het. 
\bverse En die gebed van die geloof sal die kranke red, en die Here sal hom oprig. Selfs as hy sonde gedoen het, sal dit hom vergewe word. 
\bverse Bely mekaar julle misdade en bid vir mekaar, sodat julle gesond kan word. Die vurige gebed van ‘n regverdige het groot krag. 
\bverse Elía was ‘n mens net soos ons, en hy het ernstig gebid dat dit nie moes re\"en nie, en dit het op die aarde drie jaar en ses maande lank nie gere\"en nie; 
\bverse en hy het weer gebid, en die hemel het re\"en gegee en die aarde het sy vrug laat uitspruit. 
\bverse Broeders, as een onder julle van die waarheid afgedwaal het en iemand hom bekeer, 
\bverse laat hy weet dat die een wat ‘n sondaar van sy dwaalweg bekeer, 'n siel uit die dood sal red en 'n menigte sondes sal bedek.

\setcounter{bchapter}{9}%

\bchapter Kom nou, julle rykes, ween en huil oor die ellendes wat oor julle kom. 
\bverse Julle rykdom is bedorwe, en julle klere is deur die motte verniel. 
\bverse Julle goud en silwer is verroes, en hulle roes sal tot 'n getuienis teen julle wees en sal soos 'n vuur julle vlees verteer. Julle het skatte vergader in die laaste dae. 
\bverse Kyk, die loon van die arbeiders wat julle lande afgeoes het, wat deur julle agtergehou is, roep uit; en die geroep van die maaiers het gekom tot in die ore van die Here van die le\"erskare. 
\bverse Julle het op die aarde 'n weelderige en losbandige lewe gelei; julle het jul harte vet gevoer soos op 'n slagdag. 
\bverse Veroordeel, vermoor het julle die regverdige; hy versit hom nie teen julle nie. 
\bverse Wees dan geduldig, broeders, tot op die wederkoms van die Here. Kyk, die landbouer wag op die kostelike vrug van die aarde en het geduld daarmee totdat dit die vroe\"e en die laat re\"en ontvang het. 
\bverse Julle moet ook geduldig wees; versterk julle harte, want die wederkoms van die Here is naby. 
\bverse Moenie teen mekaar sug nie, broeders, sodat julle nie veroordeel word nie. Kyk, die Regter staan voor die deur. 
\bverse Neem as voorbeeld van lyding, my broeders, en van geduld die profete wat in die Naam van die Here gespreek het. 
\bverse Kyk, ons reken hulle geluksalig wat verdra. Julle het gehoor van die lydsaamheid van Job, en julle het die einddoel van die Here met hom gesien, dat die Here vol medelye en ontferming is. 
\bverse Maar bo alles, my broeders, moenie sweer nie: nie by die hemel nie, ook nie by die aarde nie en ook geen ander eed nie; maar laat julle ja ja wees en julle nee nee, sodat julle nie onder 'n oordeel val nie. 
\bverse Is daar iemand onder julle wat ly? Laat hom bid. Is iemand opgeruimd? Laat hom psalmsing. 
\bverse Is daar iemand siek onder julle? Laat hom die ouderlinge van die gemeente inroep, en laat hulle oor hom bid nadat hulle hom in die Naam van die Here met olie gesalf het. 
\bverse En die gebed van die geloof sal die kranke red, en die Here sal hom oprig. Selfs as hy sonde gedoen het, sal dit hom vergewe word. 
\bverse Bely mekaar julle misdade en bid vir mekaar, sodat julle gesond kan word. Die vurige gebed van 'n regverdige het groot krag. 
\bverse El\'\i a was 'n mens net soos ons, en hy het ernstig gebid dat dit nie moes re\"en nie, en dit het op die aarde drie jaar en ses maande lank nie gere\"en nie; 
\bverse en hy het weer gebid, en die hemel het re\"en gegee en die aarde het sy vrug laat uitspruit. 
\bverse Broeders, as een onder julle van die waarheid afgedwaal het en iemand hom bekeer, 
\bverse laat hy weet dat die een wat 'n sondaar van sy dwaalweg bekeer, 'n siel uit die dood sal red en 'n menigte sondes sal bedek.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You'll notice that I also used the [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace). This is because you don't want a situation where the chapter number (the counter `bchapter`) only has 1 line left on the page while it actually needs 2. `\needspace{<len>}` issues a `\break` if there's less than `<len>` space left on the page.

---

Specific to your MWE, your main concern is with the setting of lengths. To quote the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf):

> The `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter` commands have global effect,
>   while the `\setlength` and `\addtolength` commands obey the normal
>   scoping rules.

As such, when you use `\setlength\NumLen{\howwide}` *within* a macro (like `\IndOne`), the change is only valid within that macro, and reverts back to it's original setting once the macro terminates. If you wish for the effects to be global, you need to store it in a box or another macro so it can be used outside the scope that it is set in.

<sub>Dit was lekker om weer Afrikaans te lees, dankie!</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am unable to install the `picins` package on my TeX-Live setup. Any ideas on how to get it working?

There is a `picinpar` package on TeX-Live, would that be similar?

I am trying to do the Bible in multiple languages. They all present this exact same problem, but at different stages. (Die rede vir die Afrikaans was maar omdat dit die eerste een van die lot was.)

Comment: @Mcgafter: It does something very similar, but I'm not sure about the "legacy" format - haven't used it at all. Visit the [`picins` package folder on CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/picins) where you can download [`picins.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex209/contrib/picins/picins.sty). Save it in your working folder, and use `\usepackage{picins}` as usual. LaTeX searches in the working folder before wading through your local TEXMF tree.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it breaks when I add my other stuff. Please have a look at the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer of egreg...

My implementation of his code. The titlemarks are failing now.
The titlemarks should show 1:1-2:5 for this example but instead it just shows the name I've given to the Table of Contents.

Should look somewhat like this:
[image]

But now looks like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15.6cm, paperheight=23.4cm, top=2cm,bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fix2col} %fixes numbering of the sections in the header for two columns

\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=0,
    bookmarksdepth=1,
    unicode=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={black},
    pdffitwindow=true,
    pdftitle={Santa Biblia},
    pdfauthor={}
}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
%   \setmainlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
    \setmainlanguage{spanish} 

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

% definition of the page style with required headers
\newpagestyle{Biblestyle}{
  \setheadrule{.02pt}
  \sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][\firsttitlemarks\thesection:\ifthesubsection{\firsttitlemarks\thesubsection}{1}---\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection]{\firsttitlemarks\thesection:\ifthesubsection{\firsttitlemarks\thesubsection}{1}---\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection}{\chaptertitle}{\thepage}
}

% sets the marks to be used (section and subsection)
\setmarks{section}{subsection}

\linespread{0.85}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\mdseries}

%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLA DE LOS LIBROS DEL}
\newcommand{\newtocname}{\LARGE{TABLA DE LOS LIBROS DEL}}
\renewcommand*\cfttoctitlefont{\huge\hfill}
\renewcommand*\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdot}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\hfill\mdseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-4.7em}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1em}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{.1em}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}

%\dottedcontents{chapter}[2.5em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}

\newcommand{\Sectionnumber}{%
  \sbox\Sectionbox{\smash{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
    \fontsize{2.2\baselineskip}{0}\selectfont\theSection}}\enspace}}

\newcounter{Section}
\newcounter{Subsection}[Section]
\newlength{\Sectionwidth}
\newif\ifFirstSubsection
\newsavebox{\Sectionbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Section}{%
  \par\vskip\z@ \@plus 2\p@
  \FirstSubsectiontrue\clubpenalty\@M
  \refstepcounter{Section}\stepcounter{Subsection}%
  \Sectionnumber\setlength{\Sectionwidth}{\wd\Sectionbox}%
  \hangindent\Sectionwidth\hangafter-2
  \leavevmode\llap{\box\Sectionbox}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\Subsection}{%
  \par\clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
  \ifFirstSubsection
    \ifnum\prevgraf=\@ne\nobreak\hspace*{\Sectionwidth}\fi
    \FirstSubsectionfalse
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{Subsection}\textbf{\theSubsection}\enspace\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0pt

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\newtocname}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{tofcontents}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\setlength\columnseprule{0pt}
\pagestyle{Biblestyle}
\newlength{\myIndent}
\Needspace*{15\baselineskip}

\twocolumn[\vspace{-0.5cm}\center{\textbf{\Huge{Génesis}}}\vspace{0.5cm}]
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Génesis}%\noindent

\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{Génesis}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\Needspace*{3\baselineskip}

\Section EN el principio crió Dios los cielos y la tierra.
\Subsection Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas estaban sobre la haz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la haz de las aguas.
\Subsection Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz: y fué la luz.
\Subsection Y vió Dios que la luz era buena: y apartó Dios la luz de las tinieblas.
\Needspace*{3\baselineskip}

\Section Y FUERON acabados los cielos y la tierra, y todo su ornamento.
\Subsection Y acabó Dios en el día séptimo su obra que hizo, y reposó el día séptimo de toda su obra que había hecho.
\Subsection Y bendijo Dios al día séptimo, y santificólo, porque en él reposó de toda su obra que había Dios criado y hecho.
\Subsection Estos son los orígenes de los cielos y de la tierra cuando fueron criados, el día que Jehová Dios hizo la tierra y los cielos,
\Subsection Y toda planta del campo antes que fuese en la tierra, y toda hierba del campo antes que naciese: porque aun no había Jehová Dios hecho llover sobre la tierra, ni había hombre para que labrase la tierra;
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this should be a followup question, rather than an answer. However, if I compile your MWE, I get a very different header on the chapter starting page.

Comment: Do you run it through XeLaTex? I will set this up as a new question tomorrow if it's not a quick fix. The MWE produces three pages of which I am referring to the last one.

Comment: Yes, of course I used XeLaTeX. The `extramarks` option to `titleps` (or `titlesec`) should be the answer. But I'm afraid I don't understand the doc. :(

Comment: @egreg Thanks looks like the solution, but I'll have to try it out first. Must say that in general these LaTeX packages docs aren't the easiest to read and understand.