# Disable automatic kerning

Tags: xetex, two-column, kerning

I want to disable automatic kerning for a few lines in my text as the `\textwidth` before `kerning` and after `kerning` is not the same. And I'm sure there is a simple command to do so, but just can't figure it out.

- Which command do I use to stop XeLaTeX from doing automatic
  `kerning`?
- Or better still which command do I use to get the
  `\textwidth` after automatic `kerning` has been applied?
- And does the
  same command also work for `\columnwidth`?

Comment: As Ulrike says, kerning and `\textwidth` are completely unrelated: (Xe)TeX typesets the words with kerning and then justifies the lines by setting the interword spaces (taking a whole paragraph into account). You probably are thinking to something different from `\textwidth`.

Comment: @egreg You might be right that I'm missing the mark on this. Although see my comment below on Ulrike's answer for more detail.

Comment: I'd choose a monospaced typeface. They're designed to look well without kerning:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the font if you can deactivate kerning:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
AV Ta \textsf{AV Ta}

{\fontspec[Kerning=Off]{Latin Modern Roman}AV Ta} %works
{\fontspec[Kerning=Off]{Arial}AV Ta} %doesn't work
\end{document}
```

But actually I doubt very much that you really want to do this. I don't understand why you think that kerning affects `\textwidth`. You should better describe with a minimal example what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've had a question in the past where I had to find the width of the text to include some `lettrine` in front of. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31459/7093 Even though in the general the answers were helpful, there remain always the cases where they just don't seem to work. So I'm just imagining that when I take the `\textwidth` it is value "A" and by the time the actual kerning and wrapping with value "B" is applied the width has changed to "A + B". Other than that I don't have a reason for thinking this. It's just in a some cases the solutions doesn't work.