# Custom titlemarks

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

My title marks are not working as I want them to. I had to move away from using the native `section` and `subsection`and therefore my title marks does not work. I had a look at the `extramarks` feature of the `titelps` package but can't figure it out especially to use alongside the `titlesec` package.

On page 3 of this MWE this is the idea of what I want:
[image: Correct]

However, this is what I get because the `section` and `subsection` does not register:
[image: Problem]

How do I add `Section` and `Subsection` into the title marks?
Or else how do I force `section` and `subsection` to still increment and actually work in the title marks?

This question relates to the discussion in one of my old questions. [Calculating the exact width of text and the lettrine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31459/7093)

Please run in **XeLaTeX.**

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15.6cm, paperheight=23.4cm, top=2cm,bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fix2col} %fixes numbering of the sections in the header for two columns

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \setmainlanguage{spanish} 

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

% sets the marks to be used (section and subsection)
\setmarks{section}{subsection}

% definition of the page style with required headers
\newpagestyle{Biblestyle}{
  \setheadrule{.02pt}
  \sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][\firsttitlemarks\thesection:\ifthesubsection{\firsttitlemarks\thesubsection}{1}---\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection]{\firsttitlemarks\thesection:\ifthesubsection{\firsttitlemarks\thesubsection}{1}---\bottitlemarks\thesection:\bottitlemarks\thesubsection}{\chaptertitle}{\thepage}
}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\mdseries}

\newcommand{\newtocname}{\LARGE{TABLA DE LOS LIBROS DEL}}
\renewcommand*\cfttoctitlefont{\huge\hfill}
\renewcommand*\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdot}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\hfill\mdseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-4.7em}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1em}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{.1em}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}

\newcommand{\Sectionnumber}{%
  \sbox\Sectionbox{\smash{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
    \fontsize{2.2\baselineskip}{0}\selectfont\theSection}}\enspace}}

\newcounter{Section}
\newcounter{Subsection}[Section]
\newlength{\Sectionwidth}
\newif\ifFirstSubsection
\newsavebox{\Sectionbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Section}{%
  \par\vskip\z@ \@plus 2\p@
  \FirstSubsectiontrue\clubpenalty\@M
  \refstepcounter{Section}\stepcounter{Subsection}%
  \Sectionnumber\setlength{\Sectionwidth}{\wd\Sectionbox}%
  \hangindent\Sectionwidth\hangafter-2
  \leavevmode\llap{\box\Sectionbox}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\Subsection}{%
  \par\clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
  \ifFirstSubsection
    \ifnum\prevgraf=\@ne\nobreak\hspace*{\Sectionwidth}\fi
    \FirstSubsectionfalse
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{Subsection}\textbf{\theSubsection}\enspace\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0pt

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\newtocname}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\setlength\columnseprule{0pt}
\pagestyle{Biblestyle}

\twocolumn[\vspace{-0.5cm}\center{\textbf{\Huge{Génesis}}}\vspace{0.5cm}]

\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{Génesis}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\Section EN el principio crió Dios los cielos y la tierra.
\Subsection Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas estaban sobre la haz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la haz de las aguas.
\Subsection Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz: y fué la luz.
\Subsection Y vió Dios que la luz era buena: y apartó Dios la luz de las tinieblas.

\Section Y FUERON acabados los cielos y la tierra, y todo su ornamento.
\Subsection Y acabó Dios en el día séptimo su obra que hizo, y reposó el día séptimo de toda su obra que había hecho.
\Subsection Y bendijo Dios al día séptimo, y santificólo, porque en él reposó de toda su obra que había Dios criado y hecho.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your sectioning commands should issue mark-commands which stores the wanted content (`\markboth{left mark}{right mark}` or `\markright{right mark}`). And your header should use this content with `\leftmark` or `\rightmark` (or `\firstleftmark` etc from the extramarks package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fermat said:

> I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin
>   is too narrow to contain.

Answer (score 0):

Perhapsthis will help you. For me, I use titlesec package, as follows:

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape}{Section \thesection}{1ex}{}
```

Which creates "Section 1.x Bla Bla Bla" for the section headings, where the spacing between 1.x and Bla Bla is 1ex.

If you want a prefix "SS" infront  of the subsection (in this case, large small caps, seperated by 1ex):

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\scshape}{SS \thesubsection}{1ex}{}
```

This will result in "SS 1.x.x Bla Bla Bla" as the subsection headings.